# List view changing views automatically?

Tags: android, listview, view

I couldn't find the problem,whenever i scrolling the view will change .pls help me out...t think android recycle views how to override ?

**1.BEFORE SCROLLING**                                                  **2.AFTER SCROLLING**
[image: BEFORE SCROLLING]                                               [image]

```
      public class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final String[] values;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public MobileArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_mobile, values);
      inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView=convertView;
    if (rowView == null) {

         rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_mobile, null);
         ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
         viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
                 viewHolder.button = (ImageView) rowView
             .findViewById(R.id.logo);

         rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
       }

       ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
       String s = values[position];

       holder.text.setText(s);
               if (mp.isPlaying()) {
              holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
            } else {
              holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
            }


    return rowView;
}static class ViewHolder {
       public TextView text;
       public ImageView button;

     }
```

}

in Main Activity

```
           protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {





      if(mp.isPlaying() && itemno == pos){

         mp.pause();



         playing= true;

         ListMobileActivity.this. imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);



      } 
      else if (playing=true && itemno== pos){
          mp.start();
          playing=false;


          ListMobileActivity.this.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
      }


      if (mp.isPlaying()&& itemno!=pos){
          ListMobileActivity.this.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);


      }

     if (itemno!=pos)
     {




          imageView = (ImageView)v. findViewWithTag(pos);




          playSample(pos);
        }            
      ListMobileActivity.this.itemno=pos;

        //Variable i, here, is from a for loop.



}

private void playSample( int position)
   {

           AssetFileDescriptor afd =  getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResourceFd(songs[position]);


           try{
               if(mp.isPlaying())


              ListMobileActivity.  this.mp.stop();






            ListMobileActivity.    this.mp.reset();
            ListMobileActivity.    this.mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),           afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
            ListMobileActivity.    this.mp.prepare();

 ListMobileActivity. this. imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);


      ListMobileActivity.this.    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

              public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                    ListMobileActivity. this.    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);


              }


              });

      ListMobileActivity.   this.   mp.start();

                afd.close();



        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
}
```

Comment: you have a bug in view recycling. post your adapter code.

Comment: @Leonidos now see.i added..

Comment: there should be code inside getView() that sets correct holder.button state.

Comment: show the code where you are setting the "viewHolder.button" image.It happens because the adapter recycles the views which goes out of visibility.Try something like what @Armaan Stranger replied.

Comment: @user2012   protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {                         
          ListMobileActivity. this.   imageView = (ImageView)v. findViewById(R.id.logo);  // and my code for playing media player...}

Comment: @Leonidos I tried all methods for holder.button state.still its not work for me.can i post my full code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using custom layout for view in list item.

So now what happens is that when you using custom layout so it will inflate the layout and it will be used again for next items.

so do as check condition in custom adapter's get view is that something similar to  this..

```
if(Song2.isplaying)
{
   imgView.setImage(pauseimage);
}
else
{
   imgView.setImage(playimage);
}
```

it will work for you.

(its just code logic representation so check criteria needs to be set by you.)

Comment: you have to check for all songs and set image according to that. Hope it Helps!!

Comment: i tried ,its not work for me,whenever i press the play button the image will change.and scroll down and up.its getting  the old image like what u suggested above .

Comment: have you checked that condition you have applied is working correctly?? update your question with the change you have made in adapter class.

Comment: you have checked MP is playing then change image. but you haven't checked which item is playing?? if that item is playing then change image of pause otherwise image should be of play button.

Comment: i knew.but how to check condition which item is playing along with mediaplayer?

Comment: You have to save whichever item is playing in Shared Preferences. which can be accessible globally. so that in adapter class you can get it.

Answer (score 0):

1.Here you are using `array[]` for listview show and you try to also show `ImageView`

```
String s = values[position];
holder.text.setText(s);
```

2.So first check the value for setImage

```
 if (s.startsWith("al")) {
      holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.baloon);
    } else {
      holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
    }
```

3.Otherwise you should make one custome adapter